# Why CalledFromWrongThreadException when no UI calls?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` which calls a webservice method and sends the returned data back to the main thread. This task does not affect any UI elements yet throws `CalledFromWrongThreadException` on the line calling `onResultSuccess`. I have many other `AsyncTask` which work in basically the exact same way, changing the called web service method and parameters, etc, but this is the only one that fails. Anyone spot what might be the problem? The `AsyncTask` looks like:

```
public static class ClockOff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> 
{

public OnAsyncResultClockOff onAsyncResultClockOff;
public void setOnResultListener(OnAsyncResultClockOff onAsyncResultClockOff) {
    if(onAsyncResultClockOff != null) {
        ResultClockOff = onAsyncResultClockOff;
    }
}

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ClockOff";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "ClockOff";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = GlobalFunction.URL;
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... strArgs) 
{
    try
    {
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
         Request.addProperty("Items", strArgs[0]);
         Request.addProperty("ID", strArgs[1]);

         SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
         soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
         HttpTransportSE transport= new HttpTransportSE(URL);
         transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
         SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;

         String ReturnMessage = ((SoapObject) result.getProperty(0)).getPropertyAsString(0);
         String ReturnMessageHeader = ((SoapObject) result.getProperty(0)).getPropertyAsString(1);
         String ActionType = ((SoapObject) result.getProperty(0)).getPropertyAsString(2);
         String SelectedCompleted = ((SoapObject) result.getProperty(0)).getPropertyAsString(3);
         String ClockOffItems = ((SoapObject) result.getProperty(0)).getPropertyAsString(4);

         //Exception thrown on the below line
         onAsyncResultClockOffItem.onResultSuccess(ReturnMessage, ReturnMessageHeader, ActionType, SelectedCompleted, ClockOffItems);
         return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        onAsyncResultClockOffItem.onResultFail();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

`OnAsyncResultClockOff` is simply:

```
public interface OnAsyncResultClockOff {
    public abstract void onResultFail();
    public abstract void onResultSuccess(String returnMessage,
            String returnMessageHeader, String actionType,
            String selectedCompleted, String clockOffItems);
}
```

And it is called via:

```
ClockOff co= new ClockOffItem();
co.setOnResultListener(onAsyncResultClockOff);
co.execute(items, ID);
```

Where `onAsyncResultClockOff` implements the `OnResultFail()` and `OnResultSuccess` methods.

Comment: May be you are creating the AsyncTask in a different thread (other than UI)

Comment: Can you post full stacktrace? My belief is that the exception is from within the actual method implementation

Comment: It is created within the exact same thread as all the other AsyncTasks, they all work as expected. @TheCapn What method implementaton do you mean? If you mean the `OnResultSuccess` method, the first line of this isn't even hit.